# NormCap OCR via Awesome Window Manager

Tags: debian, awesome, ocr

One of the coolest programs I've come across recently, is an Optical Character Recognition (OCR) program called [NormCap](https://www.appimagehub.com/p/1636854). I have it tied to a hot key, and anytime I want to copy un-highlightable text to my clipboard, I'm a hot key away from grabbing that (formerly uncooperative) text and get it into the clipboard (as text). Take that, you bad user interface! Take that, you text-image!

However, recently, I've installed [Awesome](https://awesomewm.org/). And ever since, this very same AppImage can no longer function. It either locks up Awesome completely, or sometimes it will attempt to function as normal, but you can't see the text you want to select during NormCap's attempt to allow you to do so. It's a little hard to explain, but I think it is because NormCap uses transparency during your selection steps, and you cannot see through the intended transparency via Awesome.

I feel like Awesome is saying to me: "Take that, you newbie!"

There's probably some prerequisite startup application that I need to run prior to attempting a NormCap OCR capture. Please advise.

When NormCap doesn't completely lock up Awesome, this [issue](https://github.com/dynobo/normcap/issues/154) is similar to what I see.

I used this command to see my compositor:

```
inxi -Gxx | grep compositor
```

Output:

```
Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 compositor: picom driver: loaded: modesetting
```

Then, I installed Compton instead, and replaced that in my awesome config. After a reboot, from within Awesome, it reported:

```
Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 compositor: compton driver: loaded: modesetting
```

However, this had no effect on the issue. Awesome just locks up each time I run NormCap and I have to hit ctrl+super+r to reload Awesome.

Comment: Are you using a compositor that can actually render transparency?

Comment: I'm using compton `awful.spawn.with_shell("compton")`, but would be willing to use anything that makes NormCap work.

Comment: I also install picom and added this to my awesome startup: `awful.spawn.with_shell("picom")`. NormCap still doesn't work. I wonder what the desktop environments have that awesome don't. I have no trouble with NormCap in the DEs. I'm using Debian 11, by the way.